# Can I use variables in Nginx server block for SSL Cert and Key file?

Tags: nginx, ssl, virtualhost, configuration, reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx Apache Reverse Proxy, I have multiple VHOSTS and I want to serve them all in a single nginx vhost file with support for SSL.

My server block is

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root   /var/www/$host/web;


    access_log  /var/log/mylogs/httpd/$host/access.log; 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://SERVERIP:8090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }


}
```

This is working well without SSL for all sites BUT
when I do the same for SSL support below:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/$host/ssl/$host-le.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/$host/ssl/$host-le.key;
    root   /var/www/$host/web;


    access_log  /var/log/mylogs/httpd/$host/access.log; 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://MYIP:8090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

I got errors something like this

```
ssl_certificate /var/www/$host/ssl/$host-le.crt not found
nginx config test failed
```

My vhost web files are in this format

/var/www/domain1.com/web
/var/www/domain2.com/web
/var/www/domain3.com/web

and their ssl cert and keys are in

/var/www/domain1.com/ssl
/var/www/domain2.com/ssl
/var/www/domain3.com/ssl

Please help me, I'm noob and still learning....

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx. `$host` variable will contain the first server that is defined in your `server` block which is the value that `server_name` holds. This is not going to work for multiple domains the way you've configured nginx

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can I use $http_host instead?

Comment: No I don't think that works. The `server_name` doesn't resolve to the static name of your virtual web folder. Maybe this explains a bit better: https://www.drupal.org/node/1544144

Comment: Take a look at http://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block
This requires nginx patching or using OpenResty

Comment: Sounds like a hack. Where are the good old days when SSL certificates were read with root privileges which were dropped afterwards? Without knowing your business case and other requirements... what about one certificate for all domains? Certificates can be valid for multiple domains by listing them in their _subject alternate name_ section. [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) supports up to 100 SAN entries.

Comment: Perhaps you will want a wildcard (*) certificate if all sites are subdomains of the same domain. Let's encrypt too will support it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$ssl_server_name` variable instead of `$host`.
It can be used since Nginx 1.15.9 and OpenSSL 1.0.2 version.
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html

```
ssl_certificate     $ssl_server_name.crt;
ssl_certificate_key $ssl_server_name.key;
```